# force pdf download on openshift with php

Tags: php, yii, openshift

I have an application written in php using the Yii framework and hosted on Openshift. I need to force the download of a pdf file, created with mpdf (using this extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/).

On my local server, the following line suffices to force the download with the name I want:

```
$mPDF1->Output($file_name , 'D');
```

On Openshift, however, the download is not forced and the name of the file is not correct.

This is the code from mpdf that I think it is used to create the headers of the response:

```
    else if ($dest=='D') {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        if (headers_sent())
            $this->Error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send PDF file');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', false);
        header('Content-Type: application/download', false);
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf', false);
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
    }
```

These are the response headers I get on my local server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 Jul 2015 07:15:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: public
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Last-Modified: Tue, 07 Jul 2015 07:15:34 GMT
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="invoice.pdf"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

And these are the response headers I get on Openshift:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 Jul 2015 07:05:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: public
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Last-Modified: Tue, 07 Jul 2015 07:05:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

So on Openshift it is missing:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="invoice.pdf"
```

and the file is not downloaded but shown in the browser.

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if You remove Content-Type: application/pdf. Some browsers automatically open this kind of documents. Leave only application/octet-stream.

```
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
```

Comment: Now it forces the download, but the name of the file is not the good one. The line:  Content-disposition: attachment; filename="invoice.pdf" still doesn't appear in the headers, and I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this after generating PDFs from a library.  So far no problem.

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="generated.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_to_save));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($file_to_save);
```

where `$file_to_save` is the absolute path of your pdf